# Unable to save settings TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows-10, tortoisesvn

Recently I switch to Win 10 and i installed tortoiseSVN but it looks like the app does not have all required permissions because when i change settings and hit apply nothing happens. I mean when I close popup and reopen it the settings are all back to default puls my commit log is allways empty like it can't access log or something.

I tried to set run as administrator flag on TortoiseProc but it didn't help.

Comment: TSVN doesn't need any privileges. The user running it does.

Comment: User have admin privileges maybe it has something to do with bit-locker?

Comment: No, Bitlocker has nothing to do with anything. I have Bitlocker enabled on all my machines, and it's not been an issue with any software at all including TSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it. It looks like some registry entry was malformed.
To solve this i unistalled TSVN and removed branch `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN` and install TSVN.